# error "The method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) is undefined for the type Frame"

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

I am using Visual Studio Code 2020, and it is giving me the error "The method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) is undefined for the type Frame"

The problem is line 52,

---

```
        import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        boolean loop = false;

        /* while (loop = true) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException reallyIgnored) {}

            System.out.println("Loop is working.");

        } */

    }

static class GraphicsEngine extends Component {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // Creating Graphics Shortcut

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        // Creating new framw window, declaring size

        Frame frame = new Frame();

        frame.add(new GraphicsEngine());

        int frameWidth = 700;

        int frameHeight = 500;

        frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);

        frame.setLayout(null);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.pack();

        /* Next part will create dot that moves across screen.
        It will have a loop that draws the dot, and also a loop
        that erases the previous dot. */

        g2d.SetColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));

        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().height-1, getSize().height-1);

        }

    }

}
```

---

I have tried looking for answers, but none of the ones I found had worked.

I am a noob, and picked up java a few days ago. I don't really understand much, but I am trying to learn how graphics work right now

Comment: You want to use the Swing class JFrame, not the awt class Frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the `setDefaultCloseOperation(int)` is not found as a method of your object `frame` . This could be because there is no method with that name in the frame object, or if there is such a method, there isn't one that takes a single int argument.

Looking up the API here for Frame and JFrame:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

setDeaultCloseOperation seems to be defined for the JFrame object, and not Frame. JFrame extends Frame, meaning it is a specific kind of frame. Specifically, it is a frame that has the `setDefaultOperation()` method.

Perhaps change your frame definition to `Frame frame = new JFrame();`
or `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`

Answer (score 0):

Your tag says you are asking about a JFrame, which does have the `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)` method.

However, your code is using `Frame` which is an AWT component, not a Swing component. Use a `JFrame` for Swing.

Also, you class is extending `Canvas`. For a Swing application you should be extending `JPanel` and overriding `paintComponent()`.

There is no need to use AWT components when you can use Swing.

> I am trying to learn how graphics work right now

First of all you should NEVER create a component in a painting method. A painting method should only use the Graphics object to do painting.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples to get you started.

Follow the examples from the tutorial for properly structured code.  The code you posted here is mostly wrong.